# jquery selector needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="thumb">
   <img src="thumb.jpg"/>
   <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Basically i need a selector so that when the thumb div id hovered over I can animate the child p.

I've tried this:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this > "p")animate({ "top":"35px" });
}, function() {
    $(this > "p").animate({ "top":"115px" });
});
```

Doesn't work though for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is an object, not a string, so you can't just put it into a selector. You want to use the `.find()` method instead:

```
$(this).find("p").animate({"top": "35px"});
```

Which corresponds to the selector `".thumb p"`. To get the same behaviour as `".thumb > p"`, you can use `.children("p")` instead of `.find("p")`, but the difference isn't significant here.

It's also very important that you make *no* typos such as a missing `.` before `animate` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
$('>p', this).animate({....
```

This construct extracts the first-level P elements in 'this', which is what you were trying to do. You don't need to use find(), or children() etc... to get the first level children that are P tags. I think that this construct is simpler and more intuitive.

P.S. you also have a '.' missing before your first 'animate';

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('p').animate({ "top":"35px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('p').animate({ "top":"115px" });
});
```

Comment: how bout you change find to child? that way it should be what he wanted from looking at his selector.

Comment: Well, children() is more intuitive while reading but find is super fast ;)

Comment: This is not what he was asking for. He doesn't want ALL P elements, nor as Alxandr says does he want ONLY the first child. His original code was trying to ask for all first-level child P elements. He may or may not want this, but that is effectively what he was asking for. Sorry - I'm being pedantic, my commoment is only true if he has more complex HTML than he apparently has. Ignore this comment!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.children()` to select the `<p>` tag - http://api.jquery.com/children/:

```
$(this).children('p').animate(...);
```

Comment: Just for info (not malicious): writing "$(this).children('p')" rather than "$('p', this)' is like writing "$(div).children('p')" rather than "$('div p')".

Comment: Thanks Neil +1 (and to your answer). Info on cleaner code is always welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work:

```
$(this > "p")
```

Try this:

```
$(this).find('p')
```